# MATLAB: not calculating correctly...user error?

Tags: matlab

I have been looking at this code for a while now, and cannot figure out why matlab is not calculating correctly. Does anyone see anything that I may be doing wrong with this code?

```
((1-EU_P2par3(:,1))*US_P2par3(:,1))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,2))*US_P2par3(:,2))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,3))*US_P2par3(:,3))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,4))*US_P2par3(:,4))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,5))*US_P2par3(:,5))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,6)*US_P2par3(:,6)))+((1-EU_P2par3(:,7))*US_P2par3(:,7))
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases like this, good code formatting is your friend. Using an ellipsis (i.e. `...`, the [line continuation symbol](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-5789.html#f0-5857)) to create a multi-line statement can help greatly...

It looks like you have a parenthesis in the wrong place. Your code looks like this:

```
result = ((1-EU_P2par3(:,1))*US_P2par3(:,1))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,2))*US_P2par3(:,2))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,3))*US_P2par3(:,3))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,4))*US_P2par3(:,4))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,5))*US_P2par3(:,5))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,6)*US_P2par3(:,6)))+...  %# Notice something here?
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,7))*US_P2par3(:,7));
```

And you probably want this:

```
result = ((1-EU_P2par3(:,1))*US_P2par3(:,1))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,2))*US_P2par3(:,2))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,3))*US_P2par3(:,3))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,4))*US_P2par3(:,4))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,5))*US_P2par3(:,5))+...
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,6))*US_P2par3(:,6))+...  %# Notice the change?
         ((1-EU_P2par3(:,7))*US_P2par3(:,7));
```

**EDIT:**

In addition, as [Darren mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084041/matlab-not-calculating-correctly-user-error/4084129#4084129), you will likely have to use the element-wise multiplication operator `.*` instead of the matrix multiplication operator `*`. Explanations of the arithmetic operators can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html).

Also, your calculation can be greatly simplified by vectorizing it using the function [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html), like so:

```
result = sum((1-EU_P2par3(:,1:7)).*US_P2par3(:,1:7),2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following example.

xy = rand(10,2);

a = xy(:,1)*xy(:,2);
% ??? Error using ==> mtimes
% Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

a = xy(:,1).*xy(:,2);

The error arises when you attempt to multiply vectors together. You must use the .* operator to get element-wise multiplication

Hope that helps